# HTTPS handshake to site.mycompany.com failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, https, fiddler

1. When I attempt to browse to one of my company's websites with Fiddler running, I get the following error on the CONNECT:

   "fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to site.mycompany.com failed. 
   System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing 
   the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
2. When I attempt from RestConsole of Chrome its working fine only if I switch off fiddler.
3. When I attempt to hit it from VS2015 it gives me below error

   "An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was 
   not handled in user code

   Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected 
   an error occurred on a send."